# Unusual words used to denote a specific length of time?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, time, archaicisms, obscure-terms

I'm looking for unusual/uncommon words that refer to a period of time. Something like *fortnight*:

> (*chiefly UK, Ireland, Australia, New Zealand, Singapore, dated in North America*) A period of 2 weeks. ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fortnight))

But for various different amounts of time like a year, x number of years, x number of weeks, x number of days etc.

Note: *Fortnight* is used in British English but it is uncommon/archaic in US English. Please consider it as an uncommon time-period word example for this question.

Comment: Which specific amount of time?

Comment: @KillingTime Any amount of time. I've clarified a bit further for the OP. It might appear as broad but I feel like it is a good question; and the question is also narrowed down by asking unusual words.

Comment: "unusual" is pretty subjective. Why exactly is fortnight unusual to you?

Comment: @Ivo As this is about English language and usage, it would mean uncommon in usage, unusual in common parlance. Perhaps, it could be replaced with "uncommon"; but it delivers the idea as is. _Unusual_: not usual : uncommon, rare - [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unusual)

Comment: Wikipedia has a [whole article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unusual_units_of_measurement#Time) on these.  Actually [multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_humorous_units_of_measurement#Time) [articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obsolete_units_of_measurement#Other)...

Comment: @Ivo the word "fortnight" is unusual because it was used more often in the past than it is used today. In fact, the word "fortnight" is downright archaic.

Comment: I think that the question is what quantifiers exist in the English language for different amounts of time. One can quantify different amounts of sodium chloride with scientific measures of mass such as "kilogram" or "pound". I think that the question is what non-scientific units of measure exist in the English language for quantifying different amounts of time.

Comment: @ermanen List questions are off-topic.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Where is it written exactly in the help section that list questions are off-topic? I understand that unneccessary/useless list questions can be off-topic like "what are the words starting with dis-" or "what words sound best?", but this one has some usefulness, and it has good answers already. There are examples of good list questions asked before and kept open.

Comment: @ermanen That question belongs on Meta, not in comments. But you could start with the [Don't Ask page](/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I vote to re-open. I believe 7 answers (so far) means that plenty of people found the question clear.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too broad  as it will result in a list of all possible terms.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon Fortnight is a very common word where I live (England).

Answer (score 12):

Try **sennight** when you are speaking of a week. I know of no similarly archaic word for fortnight.

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sennight)
> *sennight*
> in British English, Noun
> an archaic word for "week"

The word makes sense when compared with "fortnight"

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortnight)
> The word derives from the Old English term fēowertīene niht, meaning "fourteen nights" (or "fourteen days," since the Anglo-Saxons counted by nights).

Correspondingly, *sennight* refers to seven nights, hence a week. So a fortnight is two sennights.

Comment: [Hebdomad](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hebdomad) is another word for a period of 7 days, related to the French *hebdomadaire* (weekly).

Comment: @StuartF Excellent suggestion. I knew there was another word in my brain, but could I find it? No! Why not make it an answer?

Comment: _Heptad_ is a synonym of _hebdomad_ also. It originally means "a group of seven" from Greek _ἑπτάς, ἑπταδ-_ (heptas, heptad-), _ἑπτά_ 'seven', but also used as "a group of 7 days, a week". _Septuary_ is another rare word for things relating to the number seven, and also means "a week", from Latin _septem_ 'seven'.

Comment: These are excellent terms. They are, of course, simple contractions: _sennight_ is a shortened form of 'seven-nights', and _fortnight_ is a shortened form of 'fourteen-nights'.

Answer (score 10):

One unusual word is ***lustrum***:

> RARE 
> a period of five years. ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=lustrum%20meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB976GB976&oq=lustrum&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i67j46i175i199i512j46i512l2j0i512l5.2610j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lustrum) explains:

> A *lūstrum* ([ˈluːs̠t̪rʊ̃ˑ], plural *lūstra*) was a term for a five-year period in Ancient Rome. The *lustration* was originally *a sacrifice for expiation and purification offered by one of the censors* in the name of the Roman people *at the close of the taking of the census*. The sacrifice was often in the form of an animal sacrifice, known as a suovetaurilia.
>
> These censuses were taken at five-year intervals, thus a *lūstrum* came to refer to the *five-year inter-census period*.

e.g.

> When the tablets containing the vows to be offered for the welfare of the state ***during the next lustrum*** were handed to him, he left the duty of reciting them to Tiberius, saying that he would not take vows which he was never destined to perform. ([YourDict](https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/lustrum))

Comment: Man that font + bold + italics really made me think it said "bustrum."

Comment: In the Hollywood movie _True Grit_, a Cowboy picture starring John Wayne, made in 1969 but set in the 19th century, the character he plays uses the term lustrum to mean exactly this: a term of public office lasting 5 years.

Comment: @Ed999  John Wayne also manages other Latin quite often --> Posse --> Posse Comitatus - a legal right to copt a body of men (usually) to assist a 'Marshall'.

Answer (score 7):

A [nychthemeron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nychthemeron) is a day and a night, or a period of 24 hours.

Comment: Please edit your answer so that it follows [our Help Center's guidance on how to reference work by others](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). We are not a link farm, and a bare unattributed link does no one any good. Our reuse licence allows for plain-text reuse, and so the link would be lost if not given in actual text.

Answer (score 6):

For a period of *x* number of years; here are some unusual, archaic, uncommon, rare or obsolete (†) words from *OED*, usually directly coming from their Latin etymons and sometimes with ancient Greek roots (like *pentad*):

- Three (3) years: **triennium, triennial**
- Four (4) years: **quadrennium, quadrennial, quinquenniad, tetraëterid**
- Five (5) years: **quinquennium, quinquennial, †quinquennie, pentad**
- Six (6) years: **sexennium, sexennate**
- Seven (7) years: **septenary, septennary, septenniad** (esp. in human life), **†septimane** (also means 'a week' from Latin *septimana*)
- Eight (8) years: **†octennial** (Surprisingly, *OED* doesn't list *octennium* as an English word, which is also the Latin etymon of *octennial*)
- Eleven (11) years: **hendecad**
- Twelve (12) years: **duodecad, duodecade, †duodenary**
- Twenty (20) years: **vicennium**
- Three hundred (300) years: **tricentenary, tercentenary**
- A thousand (1000) years: **millenary**, **chiliad**, **†milliad**
- Two thousand (2000) years: **bimillenary** (*OED* adds that "for which *bimillennium* or some derivative of it would be the proper term")
- One billion (thousand million) (1000000000) years: **aeon, eon** (it is used in Geology and Astronomy; but it also has the meaning "an age of the universe, an immeasurable period of time")

These findings show that one can form a word for a period of any number of years from their Latin version (obviously more applicable for round numbers when needed). For example, one can form **novennium** for a period of nine (9) years from Latin *novennium*, from Latin *novem* 'nine' + *annus* 'year' + *-ium* (which is not listed in *OED* and which you can find usages of).

Comment: You might like to add "sesquicentenary" and "semisesquicentenary" to your list, for 150 and 75 years respectively. Perhaps also "semiquincentenary" for 250 years.

Comment: @PhilMJones Thank you for the addition. Per _OED_, "sesquicentenary" was only used for the 150th anniversary but not the time period; although one can use it for the time period too. I believe you've neologized "semisesquicentenary" and "semiquincentenary", clever. Per the last paragraph in my answer, there are many possibilities.

Comment: _Eon_ has to be used in the plural, _eons_, in order to mean 'an immeasurable period of time' (in the sense of an _unmeasured_ period).

Comment: @ermanen - I saw "semisesquicentenary" in print in 2007, and was so enamoured of the word that I used it in my father's 75th birthday card later the same year. I found "semiquincentenary" while searching online for "sesquicentenary". So while they are admittedly rather neologised words, they are not of my own invention.

Answer (score 6):

A **Moon** could be used to refer to a lunar month, also known as a **synodic month**. The length is roughly twenty-nine and a half days. Another less-known unit is the **sidereal day**, which is approximately 23 hours and 56 minutes long; there are 366 of them in a normal year.

An **Olympiad** is a period of 4 years, the first Olympiad of the modern era comprising the Gregorian years 1896 to 1899.

Comment: The calendar of ancient Greeks was indeed organised into olympiads, but is there **any** real-life example of *olympiad* being used that way in the modern era?

Comment: No, the correct term for a lunar month, in Astronomy, is a _lunation_.

Comment: @jsw, the official title of the Olympic Games in 1948 (for example) was the "Games of the XIV Olympiad". I'm not sure if it gets use outside that context though; Chess Olympiads are international competitions that are not separated by 4 years.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, there is the "millifortnight" that is 1000th of a fortnight. It's approximately 20 minutes. Occasionally used in the aerospace industry.

Comment: That is used more widely than just the aerospace industry.

Comment: A milli-Helen --> A face that will launch a single ship.

Answer (score 3):

From Wikipedia's [Unit of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_of_time#List) article:

#### Second-based

- Svedberg (100 femtoseconds)
- shake (10 nanoseconds, from "a shake of a lamb's tail"
- jiffy (1/50 or 1/60 s; one cycle of mains frequency)

#### Day-multiples

- milliday, or ".beat" (1/1000 day)
- quarantine (40 days)
- semester (126 days; wildly variable in university sense)

#### Year-multiples

- olympiad (4 yr)
- indiction (15 yr)
- jubilee (50 yr)

Comment: The word "semester" derives from the Latin for "six months". The number of teaching days in an academic semester can vary widely.

Comment: No, in physics a jiffy is the period of time that light (electromagnetic radiation) takes to travel a distance of one millionth of a millionth of a millimetre. That means that there are approx three hundred thousand billion billion jiffys in a second.

Comment: @Ed999 The unit is functionally meaningless without context. The quoted value in the anser is more properly a frame in NTSC or PAL (which was sometimes called a jiffy). In (some) physics contexts it is indeed the time it takes light to travel one femtometer. In a computer science context, it’s the length of one tick of a specific clock signal (usually the system clock) and only makes sense in the context of a specific platform (and I’m pretty sure this is where the NTSC/PAL usage came from).

Comment: Shake is "One Shake of a lamb's tail" --> nuclear bomb engineering

Answer (score 2):

- A [debt jubilee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jubilee_(biblical)): 7*7=49 years
- A [blue moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_moon#Blue_moons_between_2009_and_2037): roughly once every 3 years. (Nowadays "Once in a blue moon" means: "Not very often", and not "About every 3 years")

Answer (score 0):

Coon's-age

> Coon's age means a very long time. It is an Americanism that has
> fallen out of favor and is considered offensive by many people. Coon
> is slang for raccoon, coined in the mid-1700s. The term coon's age was
> first used in the early 1800s and in fact, owes its origin to the folk
> belief that raccoons are long-lived.
>
> [grammarist.com](https://grammarist.com/usage/coons-age/#:%7E:text=Coon%27s%20age%20means%20a%20very,that%20raccoons%20are%20long%2Dlived)

Comment: Blue Moon is second full-moon in a calendar month.